# How to get the Referrer in SF One

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a bit of a pickle. I have overloaded my custom object's view page with a VF page. This means that it can be invoked, using native functionality, from all kinds of places (search, related lists, etc). For this reason, I cannot count on parameters being passed to it.

I am trying to evaluate what page is the "referrer" to where I am. This is, the previous page.

In the desktop version, this: `document.referrer` or `ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Referer')` work perfectly fine.

However, in the SF1 version of the page both return: `https://na31.lightning.force.com/one/one.app`, which is useless to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you just need to know the referer or potentially navigate back to it? If the latter, you can use sforce.one.back(true)

Comment: I need to know the referrer, unfortunately.